# Guidance on play's execution context and creating my jdbc thread pool

Tags: scala, playframework, guice, slick

I'm trying to understand play's execution context and exactly how this fits into how I am using play with google guice.

A typical control that I am building looks like:

```
@Singleton
class MyController @Inject()(myService: MyService) extends Controller {

  def show(id: Int) = Action {
    val m = myService.getMy(id)
    Ok("this is my name " + m.name
  }

}
```

And the MyService is extending a trait that creates the apache tomcat jdbc threadpool like:

```
trait BaseService {
   val ds = LoadApacheJdbcPool.datasource
   val db = Database.forDataSource(ds)
}
```

Now from what I understand this will load in the default execution context as per:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ThreadPools

```
play {
  akka {
    event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
    loglevel = WARNING
    actor {
      default-dispatcher = {
        fork-join-executor {
          parallelism-factor = 1.0
          parallelism-max = 24
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So what does this mean, under the default settings (above), does this mean there will be up to 24 threads created?

**The real question for me is depending on what is going on, how do I get my injected service that creates a jdbc pool (which may or may not have many threads) in its own execution context and not the default on?**

I read I could wrap my calls in a future and explicity pass a execution context, but that is for calls on my 'MyService' but that was already injected and created the jdbc pool already.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure about this but the default dispatcher is configured and it can be found here:
`import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._`

it is used by most of the frameworks by using a second parameter with a `implicit` keyword thus the imported execution conntext is used.

Tomcat jdbc library has no knowledge about this so I guess if you don't configure it on your own it creates a thread pool with some default values and it has no connection with the thread pool created by akka.

So I guess you need to look for tomcat's pool configuration instead of play.

If you don't mind I would also try to take a look at other "designed for scala" frameworks for handling database. 
My pick would be slick + some library like BoneCP

Comment: I am using slick but with jdbc pool, regardless if I use BoneCP the pool has to be created in some execution context.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I believed that it is the library to manage the connections and the programmer should only give a hint of what size the thread pool should be.

Take a look here:
https://github.com/wwadge/bonecp/blob/master/bonecp/src/main/java/com/jolbox/bonecp/BoneCP.java#L438

Comment: interesting thanks, it seems to be creating different thread pools for  keep alive, connection, etc.  Not sure how this fits into the play framework threading model though.

Comment: I would just leave it as it is and don't bother it now. Think about execution context for your actors and futures. Then if there is a problem with DB just change the properties of the pool.
About the configuration of execution context you can check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22787664/how-to-detect-scala-executioncontext-exhaustion/22859136?noredirect=1#comment34911773_22859136